# Deployment to fly.io consistently failing due to APP_PATH in bin/rails file

Tags: deployment, fly

Currently trying to deploy my rails app to fly.io, it fail in the last stage (6/6) it has something to do with my APP_PATH within my bin/rails file

> ### => ERROR [build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile
> 0.3s
>
> [build 6/6] RUN SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile:
> #16 0.257 ./bin/rails: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
>
> Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c SECRET_KEY_BASE=DUMMY ./bin/rails assets:precompile]: exit code: 2

My `/bin/rails` file looks like this:

```
# !/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path("../config/application", __dir__)
require_relative "../config/boot"
require "rails/commands"
```

I have been googling for hours and it seems no one else has had this issue